# Jquery selector if has a title

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Using jquery, I want to select `input[type="text"]` elements which has a title attribute(not a specific content, just the existance of the title).

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify [multiple attributes](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/), as in the following selector:

```
$('input[type="text"][title]')
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/VW64y/

Answer (score 3):

An attribute selector without the equals clause will just test for existence:

```
$("input[type='text'][title]");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('input[type="text"][title]')
```

Adding the attribute name in brackets without any ='s will search for all elements which have that attribute